# PHP, javascript, jquery, setting hour only

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, time

I have created a small function that i need on my site successfully in php. But i now realise i actually need this in javascript or jquery as PHP will only excute this code on load.. i need this function to work with onchange on a select. The code below is my function.. Can anyone point out where i start to convert this into js/jquery like code:

```
function setTrnTime ($hr, $journeyTime){

date_default_timezone_set('GMT');

//convert current hour to time format hour
$currentHour = (date("H", mktime($hr))); 

// Journey time in hours
$journey = $journeyTime
$journey = $journey/60; // Get hours
$journey = ceil($journey); // Round off to next hour i.e. 3 hours 20mins is now 4 hours

// New Hours
$NewHour = (date("H", mktime($journey)));
$Newhour = $NewHour*60*60; // convert to seconds

// Final hour is Current Hour - JourneyTime (Hours)
$trnHour = (date('H', mktime($currentHour-$NewHour)));

return $trnHour;
}
```

With the code above, if i pass two values 06, 60: that would mean my answer would be 05. e.g. 06 is 6am. 60 is 60mins.. so 6am - 60mins = 5am.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the same in javascript using the Date object, see info here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

EDITED: Added some code, also not even using the Date object.

But do you need something that complex, doesn't the following do what you are after with less steps.

http://jsfiddle.net/WWTDc/

Comment: Please don't use link only answers. Provide an answer that is meaningful even if MDN goes down.

Comment: @gillesc link isnt as helpful. I have spent a few hours building this function in PHP and finally i get it right, only to realise i need it in js. but now im baffled as js isnt my biggest friend so to speak.

Comment: @Truth fair enough but in this case it would take me quite a while to explain the Date object :)

Comment: @gillesc: I'm not asking you to explain the whole Date object, but show a bit of example code with comments to explain what's being done.

Comment: @gillesc: It's never too late though

Answer (score 0):

If `hr` is a [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object, then it's very simple. Otherwise you can create a Date object and set its hour:

```
//! \param[in] hr Date object or hour (0--23)
//! \param[in] journeyTime journey time in minutes.
function setTrnTime(hr,journeyTime){
    var end;
    if(typeof(hr) === 'number'){
        end = new Date();
        end.setHours(hr);
    }
    else
        end = hr;

    return (new Date(end - journeyTime*60*1000)).getHours();
}
```

This will return the hour ([demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/hVvne/)).

Comment: In my code, $hr is going to be a number.. 00 to 23.. which i then convert to a date object by using mktime.. would your code still work then?

Comment: Yes, it should (see `typeof(hr)` check). However, the ceiling effect (3h20m -> 4h) is missing, but that should be simple to implement.

Comment: document.write(setTrnTime(05, 60));

This gives undefined.. maybe its to do with the ceil.. let me add ceil and see if it fixes..

Comment: Yes that works :).. but one last problem.. it shows my answer in 1 digit. in PHP i used H parament to show the numebr in 24-hour format.. is this possible with js aswell?

Comment: `var result = setTrnTime(hr,journeyTime); if(result < 10) result = '0' + '' + result;`

Answer (score -1):

See [here](http://w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) for information about Date object in JavaScript.

Comment: -1. Link only answer, w3schools? I would have downvoted twice if I could.

Comment: Thanks, I'll read this little later. I'm agree that w3schools isn't the best resource, but this is first site that came to my mind.

Comment: lol w3schools is not for my liking. Doesnt explain very well. Not as good as PHP.net manuals (which is what my goto is for PHP).. I can work better with examples to create my on functions.. but poor examples = poor understanding for me tbh.